# Iteration of operations on several columns with R

Tags: r

I have a database with information on the population of each racial group that inhabits different neighborhoods, like this one:

```
Neighborhood Race1 Race2 Race3
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A               19     1    16
2 B               20    17     2
3 C               15     2     7
4 D               17     4    15
5 E               15    20    14
```

So, I want to calculate the percentage of Race1, 2 and 3 for any neighborhood. To do so, I use this code:

```
#Firstly, I calculate the total of population by neighborhood.
df$Total=df$Race1+df$Race2+df$Race3
#Then, start the calculation of percentages
df$Race1_pr=df$Race1/df$Total
df$Race2_pr=df$Race2/df$Total
df$Race3_pr=df$Race3/df$Total
#And I obtain this:
head(df)
  Neighborhood Race1 Race2 Race3 Total Race1_pr Race2_pr Race3_pr
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A               19     1    16    36    0.528   0.0278   0.444 
2 B               20    17     2    39    0.513   0.436    0.0513
3 C               15     2     7    24    0.625   0.0833   0.292 
4 D               17     4    15    36    0.472   0.111    0.417 
5 E               15    20    14    49    0.306   0.408    0.286
```

The result is correct, but if, for example, I were to analyze 100 races, the code I am using now would be very tedious, both to calculate the total population and the percentages. I want to know if there is a way to iterate the process I am currently following with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, edited to incorporate the suggestion, offered by @stefan, to use `rowSums`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Neighborhood = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Race1 = c(19L, 20L, 15L, 17L, 15L),
  Race2 = c(1L, 17L, 2L, 4L, 20L),
  Race3 = c(16L, 2L, 7L, 15L, 14L)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(starts_with("Race"))),
         across(starts_with("Race"), ~ ./Total, .names = "{.col}_pr"))

#>   Neighborhood Race1 Race2 Race3 Total  Race1_pr   Race2_pr   Race3_pr
#> 1            A    19     1    16    36 0.5277778 0.02777778 0.44444444
#> 2            B    20    17     2    39 0.5128205 0.43589744 0.05128205
#> 3            C    15     2     7    24 0.6250000 0.08333333 0.29166667
#> 4            D    17     4    15    36 0.4722222 0.11111111 0.41666667
#> 5            E    15    20    14    49 0.3061224 0.40816327 0.28571429
```

Comment: If you don't need `Total` column can do: `mutate(across(starts_with("Race"), .names = "{col}_pr") / sum(across(starts_with("Race"))))`

Comment: You could also get rid of `rowwise` and use `rowSums` instead of `sum` to compute the `Total` which is also mentioned in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html as a more efficient approach.

Comment: Thanks, @stefan, for letting me know that! I have edited my solution to take into account your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Right, you can also do: `df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Race"), .names = "{col}_pr") / rowSums(across(starts_with("Race"))))`

Comment: Thank you! I understand that with ```starts_with("Race")``` what I tell R is something like "do the operation with those columns whose name begins with Race", right? 
If so, is there any way to do the operation but indicating the column order? Because the real dataframe has columns with the names : "black", "white", "latino", etc.

Comment: Yes, @JoséRojas: the following also works: `df %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(across(2:4)),   across(2:4, ~ ./Total, .names = "{.col}_pr"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional R solution. Obviously the most efficient solution will use `rowSums`

```
 df <- cbind(df,   # `cbind` aligns columns side-by-side
                # Now just work on the columns that have "Race" in them
             df[grepl("Race", names(df))]/ rowSums( df[grepl("Race", names(df))]) )
 df
```

Might need to do some work on the names of the new columns. The setNames function might be useful in that task.